# Solving $yy''=(y')^2-y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the ODE $yy''=(y')^2-y'$ with the initial conditions $y(0)=1, y'(0)=2$.

My attempt:

$$yy''=(y')^2-y'$$
$$(\frac {y'}y)'=(\frac 1y)'$$
$$\frac {y'}y=\frac 1y+c$$

This holds for all $x$. Plugging the initial conditions for $x=0$, we get $c=1$.
$$y'=1+y$$
Solving this got me to $y=-1$. It seems like a singular solution, but I used all methods I know and didn't get anything else.

Your ideas, please?

---

**edit**: I'm sorry about the silly question. I put my effort on getting through the hard part and lost my ability to perform simple calculations. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution of $y'=1+y$ is incorrect. Hint:
$$
{y'\over 1+y} = {d\over dx}\log(1+y)
$$

Comment: You are right. I can seperate variables. I tried other methods and forgot about this one... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The full solution with the homogeneous part is 
$$
y=-1+C·e^x
$$
and from the initial conditions $C=2$.

Comment: Oh, of course. I forgot to add the homogenous part. Well, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You got the hard part right.  But the solution to 
$$y'=1+y$$ is
$$\frac{dy}{1+y}=dx \\x + \ln K 1+y\\ y = K e^x -1
$$
And the initial conditions force $K=2$ so the answer is 
$$y = 2 e^x -1$$

Comment: I put so much effort into the hard part that I forgot how to solve simple ODEs! Thanks